# rank sum test in R vs. MATLAB: exact p-value when ties are present

Tags: r, matlab

Dear masters of R and MATLAB!

As documented, the rank sum test in R can not yield the exact p-value when the data has ties:

```
x=c(1,1,100,1000,10000);y=c(2,20,20,2000,20000);
result=wilcox.test(x,y,mu=0,paired=FALSE,
                   conf.level=0.95,exact=TRUE,alternative='greater')


Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x, y, mu = 0, paired = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95,  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Result

```
Wilcoxon rank-sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 10, p-value = 0.7358
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

BUT MATLAB DOES IT:

```
x=[1,1,100,1000,10000]';y=[2,20,20,2000,20000]';
 [p,h,stats]=ranksum(x,y,'alpha',0.05,'method','exact','tail','right')

p = 0.714285714285714
```

I guess, MATLAB does an illegal thing (pMATLAB = 0.71, not 0.74), BUT i would need to force R to yield the exact p-value (pEXACT = pMATLAB = 0.71) for testing purposes.

Thank you :)

Comment: Matlab and R both adjust for ties using normal distribution, but execute this differently. For Matlab, see [Gibbons and Chakraborti (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1201/9781439896129) & [Hollander and Wolfe (1999)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0258%2820000530%2919%3A10%3C1386%3A%3AAID-SIM463%3E3.0.CO%3B2-X). For R, see [Bauer (1972)](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1972.10481279). Neither is wrong, it's just different perspectives of the same problem.

Comment: Thx, Kat! 

I see, there are several strategies. But the core of my Q is: Can i generate R and MATLAB - commands, such that both yield the same results? 

BR, MJ:)